# I am only receiving partial output from an object Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jira

I have an object in Groovy and in this object there appears to be either a map. I am trying to get the "value" rather than the key from this objects map. How do I go about doing something like this?

This is the output I am receiving in my console the first is the object and the 2nd is the output for the property fromValues...

```
<com.atlassian.jira.issue.changehistory.ChangeHistoryItem@b791639b id=10130 changeGroupId=10113 userKey=Charley field=status projectId=10000 issueId=10217 issueKey=ICB-128 created=2019-03-12 14:19:22.0 nextChangeCreated=292278994-08-17 02:12:55.807 fromValues=[10003:To Do] toValues=[3:In Progress]>
[runner.ScriptRunnerImpl]: 10003
```

Here is my code below that I am working with so far in attempt to get this information: (Just so you understand the context... I am pulling an issue from Jira software and extracting the history of that particular issue.)

```
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
def issue = issueManager.getIssueObject("ICB-128");
def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager()
def changeItems = changeHistoryManager.getAllChangeItems(issue)
//def changeItems = changeHistoryManager.getChangeHistoriesSince(issue, since)


changeItems.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
    //log.warn(changeItems.dump())
    def last_change = changeItems[index]
    log.warn(last_change.dump())
    def text = "LAST MODIFIED FIELD:"+ last_change["field"] + "; FROM VALUE:"+ last_change["fromValue"] + "; TO VALUE:"+ last_change["toValue"]
    if (last_change["fromValue"])
    {
        log.warn(last_change["fromValue"])
    }
}
```

Edit 1: I have corrected for what @vahid suggested and now have both values returned how I want it. I have tried numerous ways to call and retrieve specifically the value for that map and nothing has worked (.get or .value or even .key)... Any suggestions?

Edit 2: Turns out this extracted field is now considered as a type "hashmap"

Comment: usually in groovy u do `.value` or `.key` to get either the key or the value so try appending `last_change["fromValue"]` to either `last_change.get("fromValue")` this should return the value or as u had it but maybe with `last_change["fromValue"].value` also isn't it fromValues rather than fromValue the above string shows with an s

Comment: LOLOL. I did not even see catch that! When I change it it captured both values instead. Thank you so much @Vahid